# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-dom

Hi I am currently running into and error in my React Web application.

**"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."**

I am aware that this error occurs because i am trying to use ReactDOM to render an object (I'm not sure exactly of which kind. HTML?) into a DIV tag as seen below.

```
        // Get display div from document
    var display = document.getElementById("display");

    // Instantiate client, using an WebSocket tunnel for communications.
    var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
    var ws_path = ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + '/ws/';

    var guac = new Guacamole.Client(
        new Guacamole.WebSocketTunnel(ws_path)
    );

    // Add client to display div
    var guacDisplay = guac.getDisplay().getElement()
    reactDom.render(guacDisplay, display);
```

When logging the object I am trying to render (guacDisplay), [I see the following object in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JC7Q.png)

How do I fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you try to display an object in UI (HTML), this error will occur.

Comment: It seems like you are mixing React with plain JS/HTML.

Comment: Asking to clarify, not to be offensive: are you aware of the differences between HTML and JSX?

Comment: Oh no offense taken. I'm this is my first project working with JSX so I'm not all that familiar with it yet. All I know is that JSX allows me to type HTML tags into my Javascript code.

Comment: I'm taking a guess here because I do not know what `Guacamole` is, but it looks like you are passing `ReactDOM.render` a DOM element, not a React element. They are not the same, and it must be a React element. If I am correct, I wonder if you really need react for this, since the only way to get this to work (`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`) would negate any benefits of using React in the first place.

Comment: *JSX allows me to type HTML tags into my Javascript code* - sort of but not really. JSX is just a **syntax** for making javascript function calls (specifically `React.createElement`). It looks a lot like HTML which makes it easier to understand how the function calls will eventually be rendered on the page, but in reality it is very different from HTML. The output of your object looks like normal HTML in the form of a DOM element, not like JSX

Comment: Oh I'm using React becaause i'm trying to integrate Apache Guacamole with an existing web application which uses React already. Is there any way I could "convert" the DOM Element into a React/JSX element?

Comment: Also may I know what makes dangerouslySetInnerHTML so ""dangerous"?

Comment: I don't know of a good way, no. And its dangerous because if you're rendering HTML from a variable, there's some inherent risk about someone putting malicious things in that variable. Especially if you don't have direct control over what gets put in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display an object/ array to an HTML element (JSX element in react), This error will occur.

```
const obj={
    name: 'john',
    age: 21
}
```

if you are trying to display obj into UI, you need to display like `obj.name` or `obj.age`

if you use directly like this

```
<div>{obj}</div>
```

will throw error.

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by "will through error."?

Comment: Okay I've given this a try. Now, In addition to my initial error, I encounter this "Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.". I really do apppreciate the help though it didnt work. Is there anything else I can try?